# Переворот карточек

Tags: javascript

```
$('.contact .catalog_btn').click(function(e){
    $('.contact').addClass('flip');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('.contact .catalog_btn2').click(function(e){
    $('.contact').removeClass('flip');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Вот код, при нажатии на кнопку получается переворот карточки туда и обратно
но проблема в том, что у меня несколько таких карточек и когда я нажимаю на кнопку, то переворачивается сразу несколько, мне нужно каждую по отдельности переворачивать

```
<div class="contact panel Journey">
                                <div class="catalog_block front">
                                    <img src="img/Poznan.png" alt="" class="img_catalog">
                                    <div class="catalog_block_title">
                                        <h2 class="catalog_block_title">
                                            Poznan
                                        </h2>
                                        <p class="catalog_block_text">
                                            Wielkopolskie
                                        </p>
                                        <a class="catalog_btn">VIEW OFFERS</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="back" id="contact">
                                    <p class="back_text">
                                        Poznan is a city in the central part of western Poland , on the Warta River , the administrative center and capital of the Greater Poland Voivodeship . 
                                        The fifth most populated city in Poland (537,643 inhabitants in 2018).
                                        A large commercial, industrial and educational center in the west of Poland . 
                                        Mechanical engineering, food, rubber, perfumery, glass and light industries are developed. 
                                        There is an international airport , a university, a medical university , theaters (including an opera house); annual international fairs are held .
                                    </p>
                                    <a class="catalog_btn2">Back</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Вот Html код если нужен

```
.panel{
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    perspective: 600px;
}

.panel .front {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}


.panel.flip .front {
  z-index: 900;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(179deg);
          transform: rotateY(179deg);
}

.panel .back {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 800;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-179deg);
          transform: rotateY(-179deg);

  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;

  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
          transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel.flip .back {
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
          transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
}
.catalog_btn{
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #f3f5f6;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #bdc8d9;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.catalog_btn2{
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #f3f5f6;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #bdc8d9;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.catalog_btn:hover{
  color: #b98000;
  background-color: #ffc74a;
}

.catalog_btn2:hover{
  color: #b98000;
  background-color: #ffc74a;
}
```

Comment: Вместо `$('.contact')` Вам нужно работать или с `e.target` или `$(this)`.

Comment: а можете по точнее сказать, а то я заменил так и так, и ничего

Comment: Можете дополнить вопрос еще и css который у Вас есть?

Comment: добавил, посмотрите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил две карточки, на вторую инлайново повесил `top: 200px;` чтобы они не налазили друг на друга, Вы уж извините. В данном случае я использовал `$(this).closest('.contact')`, вместо `$('.contact')`. В чем суть, когда на клик Вы использовали `$('.contact')` Вы добавляли и удаляли класс из всех карточек контакт, в случае с `$(this).closest('.contact')` Вы добавляете/удаляете класс с конкретной карточки, внутри которой находится кнопка на которую Вы нажали.

```js
$('.contact .catalog_btn').click(function(e){
  $(this).closest('.contact').addClass('flip');
  e.preventDefault();
});
$('.contact .catalog_btn2').click(function(e){
  $(this).closest('.contact').removeClass('flip');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.panel{
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    perspective: 600px;
}

.panel .front {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}


.panel.flip .front {
  z-index: 900;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(179deg);
          transform: rotateY(179deg);
}

.panel .back {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 800;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-179deg);
          transform: rotateY(-179deg);

  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;

  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
          transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel.flip .back {
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
          transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
}
.catalog_btn{
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #f3f5f6;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #bdc8d9;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.catalog_btn2{
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #f3f5f6;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #bdc8d9;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.catalog_btn:hover{
  color: #b98000;
  background-color: #ffc74a;
}

.catalog_btn2:hover{
  color: #b98000;
  background-color: #ffc74a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact panel Journey">
    <div class="catalog_block front">
        <img src="img/Poznan.png" alt="" class="img_catalog">
        <div class="catalog_block_title">
            <h2 class="catalog_block_title">
                Poznan
            </h2>
            <p class="catalog_block_text">
                Wielkopolskie
            </p>
            <a class="catalog_btn">VIEW OFFERS</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        <p class="back_text">
            Poznan is a city in the central part of western Poland , on the Warta River , the administrative center and capital of the Greater Poland Voivodeship . 
            The fifth most populated city in Poland (537,643 inhabitants in 2018).
            A large commercial, industrial and educational center in the west of Poland . 
            Mechanical engineering, food, rubber, perfumery, glass and light industries are developed. 
            There is an international airport , a university, a medical university , theaters (including an opera house); annual international fairs are held .
        </p>
        <a class="catalog_btn2">Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="contact panel Journey" style="top: 200px;">
    <div class="catalog_block front">
        <img src="img/Poznan.png" alt="" class="img_catalog">
        <div class="catalog_block_title">
            <h2 class="catalog_block_title">
                Card 2
            </h2>
            <p class="catalog_block_text">
                Card 2 text
            </p>
            <a class="catalog_btn">VIEW OFFERS</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        <p class="back_text">
            Card 2 Poznan is a city in the central part of western Poland , on the Warta River , the administrative center and capital of the Greater Poland Voivodeship . 
            The fifth most populated city in Poland (537,643 inhabitants in 2018).
            A large commercial, industrial and educational center in the west of Poland . 
            Mechanical engineering, food, rubber, perfumery, glass and light industries are developed. 
            There is an international airport , a university, a medical university , theaters (including an opera house); annual international fairs are held .
        </p>
        <a class="catalog_btn2">Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое!!

Comment: @ДанилРумянцев не за что) Если что, можете выбрать ответ как верный и проголосовать за него.

Answer (score 0):

При нажатии на карточку вы добавляете класс `.flip` **всем** своим карточкам. Вместо этого следует вешать нужные классы только на 1 конкретную:

```
$(".contact").click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).toggleClass("flip")
})
```